# Simplify not working

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, assumptions, integral-equations

I am trying to simplify the following expression

[image]

code:

```
Cos[(Sqrt[Integrate[(-1 - I)*dper*Ex[t1], {t1, 0, Infinity}]]*
    Sqrt[Integrate[(-1 + I)*dper*Ex[t1], {t1, 0, Infinity}]])/hbar
```

with previous assumption declared as

```
$Assumptions = Element[\[Alpha] | \[Beta] | ap | a0 | E0 | Ep | t | Ex[t1] | Ex[] |
 t1 | Nd | T | hbar | dper | dpara, Reals];
```

However, somehow it seems Mathematica is not able to understand (-1+i)dper does not depend on t1, and therefore, it cannot be simplified. Any thoughts on how I could improve that?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `Ex`? Should it be `Exp`?

Comment: Can you, please, include the code shown in the picture as easily copy-&-paste-able text in a code block here?

Comment: @CATrevillian Here it is. Sorry!

Comment: The code yo included is not WL. and what is `dper`?

Comment: To paraphrase the question: Why is `Integrate[a*f[x], x]` auto-simplified to `a*Integrate[f[x], x]` but `Integrate[a*f[x], {x, x1, x2}]` remains as-is without extracting the constant `a` from the integral?

Comment: @denis - prior to copy and paste of your code, convert it to `Raw InputForm`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your expression:

```
expr = Cos[(Sqrt[Integrate[(-1 - I)*dper*Ex[t1], {t1, 0, Infinity}]]*
      Sqrt[Integrate[(-1 + I)*dper*Ex[t1], {t1, 0, Infinity}]])/hbar];
```

Try this:

```
expr2 = Simplify[
  expr /. Sqrt[Integrate[a_*Ex[t1], {t1, 0, Infinity}]] :> 
     Sqrt[a]*Sqrt[(Integrate[Ex[t1], {t1, 0, Infinity}])] /. 
   Sqrt[a_]*Sqrt[b_] :> Sqrt[a*b], dper \[Element] Reals]

(*  Cos[(Sqrt[2] Abs[dper] \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(Ex[
     t1] \[DifferentialD]t1\)\))/hbar]  *)
```

[image]

Have fun!